# Cant reach hbase (on S3) from pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have created a cluster on emr and I want to use hbase with pyspark. I am new to using distributed systems so I might make amatuer mistakes but connecting to hbase from pyspark feels very hard.

My code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test hbase").config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem").getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "quorum_url")
spark.conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181")
spark.sparkContext.setSystemProperty("hbase.rootdir", "s3://emr-test/data/")
spark.sparkContext.setSystemProperty("hbase.cluster.distributed", "true")
spark.sparkContext.setSystemProperty("hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.upperLimit", "0.5")

spark.read.format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark").option("hbase.table", "example_table").load()


    
print(hbase_tables)

spark.stop()
```

I have made sure the table exists but logging into hbase shell from the master node and reading the table.

The error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 314, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 179, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o238.load.
: org.apache.spark.SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find the data source: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark. Please find packages at `https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html`.
```

I am using Amazon EMR version emr-7.0.0 so the installed applications versions are Spark 3.5.0 and Hbase 2.4.17.

how i am executing:
`spark-submit test.py`
Maybe I am missing jars. If that is the case, can someone tell me how i can get the jars that are meant for my version of hbase and spark?

Comment: Use Apache Phoenix.  That is what most did.

Comment: cut the spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl declaration; its stack overflow superstition. better to read the spark and hadoop s3a docs

Comment: I have bumped in to Hortonworks connector for hbase-spark but it seems that the version they support are quite old. The github [repo](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc) was updated 4 years ago. But the connector from apache seems quite new but I cant figure out how the versioning works in this case or what is the url of jar repo is.

Comment: @thebluephantom can you elaborate on how you do that? I installed phoenix but it seems that i cant see that table. This is my read statement,

```spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbc_url) \
    .option("driver", "org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver") \
    .option("dbtable", "SYSTEM.CATALOG") \
    .load()```

Comment: Too long ago. I used NIFI at that time. I will have look for u later.